# ArcGIS Pro SDK EditBox update on Project Change

Tags: arcgis-pro-sdk

I have an EditBox displaying the ArcGIS Pro project path.  When I open a different project, the EditBox does not update with the new project path.

```
internal class ProjectPathEditBox : ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Contracts.EditBox
    {
        public ProjectPathEditBox()
        {

            string stringURI = Project.Current.URI;
            Text = stringURI;
        }
    }
```

How do I get the `Text` value to update when opening a new project?  Is an EditBox the best control to use?

Comment: I noticed the code didn't get formatted great.  Here is another try:

Comment: internal class ProjectPathEditBox: ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Contracts.EditBox {public ProjectPathEditBox() {string stringURI = Project.Current.URI; Text = stringURI: }}